# What are black sausage pieces used for in Crocodile Locomotive set 10277?

Tags: trains, piece-usage

After assembly I have these 5 pieces left. Should I have put them somewhere? I can't find any missed step that would use them.  So why are these there at all?

[image: picture of pieces]

Comment: For feeding the crocodile...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These are placed next to the magnets at the front and the back of the train. See step 142 in the instructions.

4 are needed and there is 1 spare.

[BrickInstructions](https://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/10277/Crocodile_Locomotive) shows it here:
[image: step 142]

Comment: Does the set come with minifigs? You'd be able to pose one holding onto the last "spare" one, right?

Comment: Yes, it does. 1 male and 1 female in blue overalls. "The 2 LEGO®minifigures with tools, display track and plaque provide lots to explore after building the classic train." https://www.lego.com/en-gb/product/crocodile-locomotive-10277